# AVG(User_Score) in T-SQL is returning wrong value

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, average

I imported an Excel sheet into SMSS about video games, there are around 10,000 `User_Scores`, but when I run the code below it seems to only give me the max user_score per publisher... I was looking to get the average user_score for each publisher (gaming company). Help! (I did previously have a where User_score is not null, but I found out AVG ignores null so I did remove it)

```sql
SELECT 
    Publisher, 
    AVG(User_Score) AS AVGScore, 
    AVG(User_Count) AS AVGCount 
FROM 
    [Video Game Sales]..Video_Games_Sales_as_at_22_Dec_$
GROUP BY
    Publisher, User_Score
ORDER BY
    AVGScore DESC
```

Nothing that the intellisense thought would work. I tried `AVG(CAST(USER_SCORE AS AVGScore)`, my next attempt was going to try and use a sum/count of `user_score`.

Comment: Why are you grouping and aggregating `User_Score`? The average of a single value will always be that single value. The average of one 5, ten 5's, or a million 5's is still 5.

Comment: Grouping the Publisher's average User_Score..

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what the `GROUP BY` does. it's used to define the distinct groups you want. So, for the above, you will get one row per each *distinct* group of `Publisher` and `User_Score`; so you're going to see each publisher multiple times (once for each score), and the average of those scores will be the score.

Comment: Please learn how to use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query groups by the unique combination of `Publisher` and `User_Score`, which isn't what you wanted. Remove the `User_Score` from the `group by` clause and you should be OK:

```sql
SELECT   Publisher, AVG(User_Score) as AVGScore, AVG(User_Count) as AVGCount 
FROM     [Video Game Sales]..Video_Games_Sales_as_at_22_Dec_$
GROUP BY Publisher
ORDER BY AVGScore desc
```

Comment: This still has `User_score` in the `GROUP BY`. ;)

Comment: @ThomA yikes! thanks for noticing! Edited and fixed.

Comment: @ThomA I guess I've caught a case of copy-and-bug... :-)

Comment: @N-Night If this answers your question then please consider marking the Accept answer flag.

Comment: Thanks, I was pressing everything else. Obviously a new user.